# Silent installation of SQL Server service pack not working with parameters

Tags: sql-server, powershell

iam installing service pack on SQL Server through silent installation.
code is working without parameters but with parameters ts not working

code without parameters

```
param([string]$servername)
param([string]$instance)


$path1="D:\sysdba\SQLServer2008R2SP2-KB2630458-x64-ENU.exe"


Try
{

$SqlQuery = "SELECT * from dbo.BlockingInfoOutput;"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection



$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Servername; Database = master; Integrated Security = SSPI;"
write-host $SqlConnection.ConnectionString 
$command=$path1

write-host $servername
write-host $instance

$arg1="/instancename=" + $instance
$arg2= "/quiet" 
$arg3= "/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=TRUE"

write-host $arg1
write-host $instance
# D:\sysdba\SQLServer2008R2SP2-KB2630458-x64-ENU.exe  /instancename=SQLINST /quiet  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=”TRUE” | Out-File d:\sysdba\test.txt


write-host $path1 $arg1 $arg2 $arg3

          Write-Host "Success." 

}

Catch
```

{
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White "Fail"

```
    $errText =  $Error[0].ToString() 


        if ($errText.Contains("network-related")) 


    {Write-Host "Connection Error. Check server name, port, firewall."}   

    Write-Host $errText 


    continue
```

}

code with parameters

```
& $path1 $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

this is i am using as concatenation but not working?

any help please

Comment: iam passing this in powershell command prompt  Ps: d:\sysdba\test.ps1 cx-siscsqltest\sqlinst sqlinst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test the command with your exe and parametrs. But try this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $PathToExe-ArgumentList "/quiet" -Wait
```

Comment: while using this  d:\sysdba\test.ps1 cx-siscsqltest\sqlinst sqlinst  its showing me write-host $servername , but iam not able to see instance name can you please check code is something is missing

Comment: PS D:\sysdba> d:\sysdba\test.ps1 cx-siscsqltest\sqlinst sqlinst
The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\sysdba\test.ps1:3 char:6
+ param <<<< ([string]$instance)
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (param:String) [], CommandNotFou
   ndException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
Server = cx-siscsqltest\sqlinst; Database = master; Integrated Security = SSPI;
cx-siscsqltest\sqlinst

Comment: /instancename=;

D:\sysdba\SQLServer2008R2SP2-KB2630458-x64-ENU.exe /instancename=; /quiet /IACCE
PTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=TRUE
Success.

Comment: its just not displaying instance name  not sure why

Comment: you cant use two param(). Do it like that: param([string]$servername, [string]$instance)